Is the domain I'm searching for registered or not?
There is domain I want (TLD is .space). When I search on Namecheap it seems to be available for $1500, but if I search on GoDaddy (or others) it says that the domain is taken but that they "might be able to help [me] get it" for $150 broker fee or something.
I also notice that the domain was registered a month ago - suspiciously around the time that I started searching for it a fair bit.
My questions:

Is the domain actually registered?
Does the fact that it is "available" on Namecheap mean that they have registered it? Or perhaps someone is selling it via Namecheap?
Is there any chance of me getting the domain any cheaper if I use the GoDaddy brokering service or something similar? Or will they just come back with the Namecheap price (and I will have had to pay an extra $150 for the brokering)?
Is it possible that if someone is searching for a domain, that activity is noticed by someone else and they buy it or increase the price (if already registered)? Or are these things just coincidences?


Never use registrars websites to search for domain names you want to register. They get up to dirty tricks to make money - jacking up the price, registering the domain themselves. Install whois on your machine and learn how to use it.

"install whois" - incomplete answers do not help the OP or anyone else.  Besides, what is there to install?  Use https://lookup.icann.org

Perhaps you could fill in the blanks - OP did not mention what OS they have available / use regularly.

That's my point.  A complete answer would qualify that you can only "install whois" on certain operating systems.  If people don't understand that, then your answer isn't helpful which defeats the purpose of Stack Exchange/

I was not aware that there were operating systems which support TCP/IP (and presumably running webservers) but not whois in common usage.
